# Chat application in android without a server

Tags: android, android-emulator, chat

Is it possible to create a chat application in android  between two systems without implementing a server as a middle ware? I have created an application , and I want to make the chat possible between two different emulators on two different systems , I need some help guys ...!!!

Comment: At some point you need to store the chat message, so you need a database. You can store and duplicate your data on the 2 devices but you have to synchronize it. I would really recommend the server approach, to avoid the synchro thing

Comment: @Plumillon  : Yes , I have checked that method , but is there any simple methods to develop a middle ware ?  I was trying to deploy a server using tomcat and mysql ..and JDBC connector but it was likely a little bit difficult for me , I am a beginner .. any suggestions ?

Comment: It depends on your skill (Java, PHP, ASP ?), you started in a good direction here :) I don't know a "simple" method different to go for the path of documentation and pain in the ass time :p

Comment: @Plumillon : haha well I like that Plumillon :)Thanks I am gonna give a best try anyway wish me luck .. Good day !

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible thats how I made my Phd project. When my application is started it asks the user to chose if it will be a "server" or client. And on the second phone it choses the other. But there is nothing in the middle of the communication.

Comment: Its ok dude , I was just asking about a method like port forwarding ..well thanks for the answer good day!

Answer (score 1):

XMPP is often used for Chat. It is typically used with a server but there also exists an extension [XEP-0174 Serverless Messaging](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html) supporting chat without an intermediate server.
I don't know whether there are Android libraries supporting this though.

An alternative could be to

- use eg SSDP (or Bonjour(mDNS + DNS-SD)) for discovery of devices
- write your own protocol on top of it

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a solution which may work.

You can use http://programminglife.io/android-http-server-with-nanohttpd/

NanoHttpd and if both mobile phone are in same network and they can ping each other there is a possibility that you can easily create an app which help to create the chat app peer to peer mobile.